# Entity is not persisted in Exposed after @Transactional method in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have the following DAO classes

```
package exposed.example

import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.EntityID
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.UUIDEntity
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.UUIDEntityClass
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.UUIDTable
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SchemaUtils
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.transaction
import java.util.*

object CustomerTable: UUIDTable(name = "customer") {
    val name = varchar(name = "name", length = 255).uniqueIndex()
}

class CustomerDAO(id: EntityID<UUID>): UUIDEntity(id) {
    companion object : UUIDEntityClass<CustomerDAO>(CustomerTable)

    var name by CustomerTable.name
}

object OrderTable: UUIDTable(name = "orders") {
    val customer = reference(name = "customer_id", foreign = CustomerTable)
    val product = varchar(name = "product", length = 255)
}

class OrderDAO(id: EntityID<UUID>): UUIDEntity(id) {
    companion object : UUIDEntityClass<OrderDAO>(OrderTable)

    var customer by OrderTable.customer
    var product by OrderTable.product
}
```

If I create transaction manually then entities got persisted in the database, see the code below

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Database.connect("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb", driver = "org.postgresql.Driver", user = "test", password = "testpassword")
    transaction {
        SchemaUtils.create(CustomerTable, OrderTable)
        val customer = CustomerDAO.new {
            name = "Alice_${System.currentTimeMillis()}"
        }

        OrderDAO.new {
            this.customer = customer.id
            product = "MegaProduct"
        }
    }
}
```

But if I use the same `CustomerDAO`and `OrderDAO` in a @Transactional method in spring boot app, strange things are starting to happen.

```
package exposed.example

import org.jetbrains.exposed.spring.SpringTransactionManager
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import javax.sql.DataSource


open class Service {

    @Transactional
    open fun createCustomer(name: String): CustomerDAO {
        return CustomerDAO.new {
            this.name = name
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    open fun createOrder(customer: CustomerDAO, product: String): OrderDAO {
        return OrderDAO.new {
            this.customer = customer.id
            this.product = product
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    open fun doBoth(name: String, product: String): OrderDAO {
        return createOrder(createCustomer(name), product)
    }

}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
open class App {

    @Bean
    open fun transactionManager(dataSource: DataSource) = SpringTransactionManager(dataSource)

    @Bean // PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor with proxyTargetClass=false, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1844
    open fun persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() = PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor()

    @Bean
    open fun service() = Service()

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val app = runApplication<App>(*args)
    val service = app.getBean(Service::class.java)

//    val customer = service.createCustomer("Alice1")
//    service.createOrder(customer, "SpringProduct")

    service.doBoth("Bob", "SpringProduct")

}
```

Only `customer` is created but not the `order` in this case. If I uncomment two lines above then customer won't be created and the second line will cause NPE.

So in @Transactional method the entity gets persisted only if referenced by another or queried.

How to make it to be persisted anyway?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: That's strange, I copy-pasted your code as a test here (https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/blob/master/spring-transaction/src/test/kotlin/org.jetbrains.exposed.spring/SpringTransactionEntityTest.kt) and everything goes well.

Comment: @Tapac please try to run it as a standalone app, you would need to add application.yml with the datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is gone in exposed 0.10.2

Answer (score 0):

So far I have found this workaround:

```
@Transactional
    open fun createOrder(customer: CustomerDAO, product: String): OrderDAO {
        val id = OrderTable.insertAndGetId {
            it[this.customer] = customer.id
            it[this.product] = product
        }
        return OrderDAO.findById(id)!!
    }
```

But it's a dirty mix of DSL and DAO API, any improvement appreciated.